# REG SAVE HKLM\SOFTWARE give me different file size when running from ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, .net, regedit, processstartinfo

I'm trying to save the Hive Registry File called `HKLM\SOFTWARE` from a C# application.

When I run the the following command (from CMD) `REG SAVE HKLM\SOFTWARE C:\TEST` it give me a file with a size of about 90MB.

So, I expected that by running this command through the Process and ProcessStartInfo class in a C# Console Application, it would give me the same result. **NO**.
It produces a file of about 8MB, obviously with less data!

Here is the C# code:

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo("REG", "SAVE HKLM\SOFTWARE C:\TEST")
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = false,
    RedirectStandardError = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
};

Process.Start(start).WaitForExit();
```

Why it gives me a smaller file?
How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you just saving the 64-bit registry hive?

Comment: Maybe you're running one command from a 32-bit process and the other from a 64-bit process? [They use different registry hives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Type `reg save /?` to get command help.  You'll discover the /reg:32 and /reg:64 options.